# JSP - Separating HTML forms in JSP Functions

Tags: java, jsp, web

I have my JSP that controls the frame behavior of my page as the following:

```
<%
    print_header();
    String especialidade = request.getParameter("especialidade");
    String medico = request.getParameter("medico");
    String paciente = request.getParameter("paciente");
    String data_consulta = request.getParameter("data_consulta");
    String convenio = request.getParameter("convenio");
    if (especialidade == null) {
        print_especialidade_form();
    } else if(paciente == null) {
        print_agendamento_form();
    }
    print_footer();
%>
```

I have the definition of the functions defined in the same JSP, delimited by `<%!` and `%>` tags, but the creation of the form, that happens inside of those functions, get executed even if the function isn't called like `print_footer();` for instance.

I 'm used to programming in ASP and I could easily do these there, but I'm having a hard time migrating to JSP. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you mean to put `print_footer();` inside an `else` statement at the end?

Comment: btw, don't use scriptlets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files

Comment: No @Ramanlfc, "print_header();" and "print_footer();" are always supposed to happen.